# Spark Job creates too much tasks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I am developing a code in Scala to launch into a Cloudera cluster.
My code is:

```
def func_segment (model: String) : String = {
    if(model == "A1" || model == "B1" || model == "C1" || model == "D1") "NAME1" 
    else if (model == "A2" || model == "B2") "NAME2"
    else "NAME3"
}
val func_segment_udf = udf((model: String) =>{
    if(model == "A1" || model == "B1" || model == "C1" || model == "D1") "NAME1" 
    else if (model == "A2" || model == "B2") "NAME2"
    else "NAME3"
})
def func_assetType (sp_rating : String) : String = {
    if(sp_rating.startsWith("A")) "B00001"
    else if(sp_rating.startsWith("BBB")) "B00002"
    else "B00003"
}
val func_assetType_udf = udf((sp_rating : String) => {
    if(sp_rating.endsWith("u")) func_assetType(sp_rating.dropRight(1))
    else func_assetType(sp_rating.dropRight(1))
})
val func_nctaFormat_udf = udf((ncta:Int) => {
    "%018d".format(ncta)
})
def func_nctaFormat (ncta:Int) : String = {
    "%018d".format(ncta)
}
def func_assetTypeTotal (datos : List[String]) : String = {
    if (datos(0) != null && datos(0) != "" && ! datos(0).startsWith("SIN") ) func_assetType(datos(0))
    else if (datos(1) != null && datos(1) != "") func_assetType(datos(2))
    else func_assetType(datos(4))
}

val repos_cpty = sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT * FROM bu_local.vw_cpty
""")

val repos_aqa = sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT * FROM bu_local.vw_aqa
""")
val repos_garan = sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT * FROM bu_local.vw_repos_garan
""")
val repos_rating_conversion = sqlContext.sql("""
select upper(segment) as segment, internal_rating, sp_rating from bu_local.vw_rating_conversion
""")

val internal_rat = repos_garan.join(repos_cpty, repos_garan.col("id_garante") <=> repos_cpty.col("cpty")).join(repos_aqa, repos_cpty.col("parent") <=> repos_aqa.col("gl_code")).withColumn("segment",func_segment_udf(col("model_id_3"))).select("id_emisor_garan","parentrating","segment").distinct()

val repos_aux2 = internal_rat.join(repos_rating_conversion, (internal_rat.col("segment") <=> repos_rating_conversion.col("segment")) && (internal_rat.col("parentrating") <=> repos_rating_conversion.col("internal_rating")))
.withColumn("asset_type_aux2", func_assetType_udf(col("sp_rating")))
.select("id_emisor_garan","asset_type_aux2").distinct()

val internal_rat2 = repos_garan.join(repos_cpty, repos_garan.col("id_garante") <=> repos_cpty.col("cpty")).join(repos_aqa, repos_cpty.col("parent") <=> repos_aqa.col("gl_code"))
.withColumn("segment",func_segment_udf(col("model_id_3")))
.select("id_garante","parentrating","segment").distinct()

val repos_aux1 = internal_rat2.join(repos_rating_conversion, (internal_rat2.col("segment") <=> repos_rating_conversion.col("segment")) && (internal_rat2.col("parentrating") <=> repos_rating_conversion.col("internal_rating")))
.withColumn("asset_type_aux1", func_assetType_udf(col("sp_rating")))
.select("id_garante","asset_type_aux1").distinct()

val repos_final = repos_garan.join(repos_aux2.withColumnRenamed("id_emisor_garan","id_emisor_garan_aux2"), repos_garan.col("id_emisor_garan") <=> repos_aux2.col("id_emisor_garan"))
.join(repos_aux1.withColumnRenamed("id_garante","id_garante_aux1"), repos_garan.col("id_garante") <=> repos_aux1.col("id_garante"))
.withColumn("contract_id", func_nctaFormat_udf(col("ncta")))
.withColumn("asset_type_code", when((col("rating_ext") !== null) && (col("rating_ext") !== "") && (!col("rating_ext").startsWith("SIN")), func_assetType_udf(col("rating_ext"))).otherwise(when((col("tipo_garante") === "National/Sovereign Government") || (col("tipo_garante") === "GOVT NATIONAL"),func_assetType_udf(col("rating_ext_sov"))).otherwise(when((col("isin") !== null) && (col("isin") !== ""),func_assetType_udf(col("asset_type_aux2"))).otherwise(func_assetType_udf(col("asset_type_aux1"))))))
.withColumn("guarantee_code",col("asset_type_code"))
.select("contract_id","asset_type_code","guarantee_code","venc_gran")
```

I can do a .show() on each val and It works perfectly less at repos_final where it creates 79999 tasks and it crashes. I supose that i have a no efficient code because I don't have too much expirience.

Any suggestions?

Comment: most of your udf functions can be replaced by inbuilt functions. and some of the joins can be avoided. sample data of each input tables would help you get the answers.